# MongoDB with C# Driver - date format with sort

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to convert ISODate to string format like "2019-06-27" this, and also need to apply a sort on it by date. However, I've converted date in required format but messing up with date sort due to date string format which is earlier converted.

**App Environment**

1. .NET MongoDB Driver - 2.0
2. MongoDB version - 3.2

This is how the document stored in the MongoDB collection:

```js
{ 
  "_id": "9d78d0e8-7b13-4487-88a3-d91d64f29b38",
  "Number": "001",
  .......,
  .......,
  "createdon": {
        "$date": "2019-09-19T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
  "modifiedon": {
        "$date": "2019-12-17T19:52:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

And this is the working C# function but without date sort:

```
public string GetData(Data.DataModel.TestModel model)
    {
        string collectionName = "testCollection";
        BsonDocument sort = new BsonDocument();
        BsonDocument match = new BsonDocument();
        BsonDocument project = new BsonDocument();

        int skip = model.skip;
        int limit = model.limit;

        try
        {                
            match.Add();

            project.AddRange(new BsonDocument { 

                                { "TDLNumber", 1 },
                                { "createdon", new BsonDocument("$dateToString", 
                                    new BsonDocument("format", "%Y-%m-%d").Add("date", "$createdon")) // format like 2019-06-27
                                },
                                { "modifiedon", new BsonDocument("$dateToString", 
                                new BsonDocument("format", "%Y-%m-%d").Add("date", "$modifiedon"))// format like 2019-06-27
                                }
                    });

            sort.AddRange(new BsonDocument { { "createdon", -1 }, { "modifiedon", -1 } });

            List<BsonDocument> lstReslut = dbo.FindAggDynQuery(collectionName, match, project, skip, limit, sort);
            QueryResult = lstReslut.ToJson();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            QueryResult = "[]";
        }
        return QueryResult;
    }
```

But if I do without date convert it works perfectly like this

```
 { "createdon", 1},
 { "modifiedon",1},
// { "createdon", new BsonDocument("$dateToString", 
//      new BsonDocument("format", "%Y-%m-%d").Add("date", "$createdon")) // format like 2019-06-27
// },
//{ "modifiedon", new BsonDocument("$dateToString", 
//      new BsonDocument("format", "%Y-%m-%d").Add("date", "$modifiedon"))// format like 2019-06-27
//}
```

Here's databae layer query function:

```
public List<BsonDocument> FindAggDynQuery(string collectionName, BsonDocument find, BsonDocument project, int skip, int limit, BsonDocument sort)
    {
        using (var connectionManager = new Test.Data.ConnectionManager())
        {
            var _collection = connectionManager.GetDBCollection(collectionName);
            var result = _collection.Find(find).Sort(sort).Project(project).Skip(skip).Limit(limit).ToListAsync().Result;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

What's going wrong here. Any help would be appreciate!!

Comment: In your C# driver, you are sorting `descendant`, while before converting into string, you are sorting `ascending`. Is It correct? Other thing: why you don't Sort dates being Date where mongodb can use indexes and then with `$project` you convert them?

Comment: 1. Sort only descending(both key) 2. Then convert date to a string, how?

Comment: You need to use `aggregate`. Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/36407426/3710490

Comment: @Valijon Thanks for the hint to use aggregate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**After working on couple of hours, here's my optimized answer.**

Changes in the GetData method using the Aggregate method:

```
match.Add();

project.AddRange(new BsonDocument { 

                            { "TDLNumber", 1 },
                            { "createdon", 1 },
                            { "modifiedon", new BsonDocument("$dateToString", 
                            new BsonDocument("format", "%Y-%m-%d").Add("date", "$modifiedon"))// format like 2019-06-27
                            }
                });

BsonDocument expAddfield = new BsonDocument(new BsonDocument("$addFields", new 
BsonDocument("createdon", new BsonDocument("$dateToString",
                                                                                                                        new BsonDocument
                                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                                            { "date", "$createdon" }, 
                                                                                                                            { "format", "%Y-%m-%d" }
                                                                                                                        }))));

sort.Add("createdon", -1);

List<BsonDocument> lstReslut= dbo.FindAggDynNoGroupWithSortSkipLimit(watertrackingCollection, expProject, match1, expAddfield, sort, skip, limit);

QueryResult = lstReslut.ToJson();
```

Aggregate Method

```
public List<BsonDocument> FindAggDynQuery(string collectionName, BsonDocument expProject, BsonDocument expMatch, BsonDocument expAddfield, BsonDocument expSort, int skip, int limit)
    {
        var connectionManager = new ez2Track.Data.ConnectionManager();
        var _collection = connectionManager.GetDBCollection(collectionName);
        var agg = _collection.Aggregate().Project(expProject).Match(expMatch).AppendStage<BsonDocument>(expAddfield).Sort(expSort).Skip(skip).Limit(limit);
        var result = agg.ToListAsync().Result;
        return result;
    }
```